# Go back to login action while session expires

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want that my page should be redirected to login page when the session expires Here is my code , I don't know what is wrong with it , bt it is not working , can anyone help?

code

```
public class SessionExpireAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
    // check  sessions here
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["username"] == null)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Account/Login");
        return;
    }
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
}

namespace FinalTimesheetProject.Controllers
{
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    static string startdate,enddate;

    //
    // GET: /Base/

    [SessionExpire]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Aayushi , have you tried to debug ? what value is coming in session ?

Comment: hey , i had solved it , thanks a ton

Comment: Share the root cause and solution also , if possible. It will be beneficial for others if someone got into similar problem

Comment: yeah sure .......

Answer (score 0):

Heyaa , I had solved it , actually the code which i had posted earlier doesn't work with ajax post requests .. so i had written different condition for it , and now it works.. thanks.. and write this code into your controller because with class redirectToAction method won't work

code:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session["username"] == null)
        {
            //CHECK REQUSET TYPE = GET
            if (Request.RequestType.Equals("GET"))
            {
                //IF REQUEST IS AJAX
                if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                {
                    filterContext.Result = Json("SESSION_KILLED", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    return;
                }
                //NORMAL REQUSET
                else
                {
                    filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction("Login","Account");
                    return;
                }
            }
            //REQUEST TYPE IS POST
            else
            {
                filterContext.Result = Json("SESSION_KILLED", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                return;
            }
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
```